# Set value of event range does not recognize custom function that auto inputs a string in range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**I have the below function which auto-fills column C with the word 'Text'**

```
function emptycellfilling() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('source_sheet');
  var empty = ""
  for(var i=2; i<=ss.getLastRow(); i++){
    var val= ss.getRange(i,1).getValue();//select col num

    if(val!=empty){ss.getRange(i,3).setValue(['Text']);}//select target col num and value you want to fill inside, here is 0
  }
  
}
```

**I have the below code to sync the two sheets**

```
function ss1OnEdit(e){
  if(e.range.getSheet().getName()!='source_sheet') return;
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rGns0DGQbjlEpxTbdy1T_-m2oh7eK8tM9xyDzGqahJo").getSheetByName("target_sheet").getRange(e.range.getA1Notation()).setValue(e.range.getValue());
}

function createSS1OnEditTrigger() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var trgs=ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  var found=false;
  for(var i=0;i<trgs.length;i++) {
    if(trgs[i].getHandlerFunction()=="ss1OnEdit") {
      return;
    }
  }
  if(!found) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("ss1OnEdit").forSpreadsheet(ss.getId()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

However when the auto-fill function runs the String value 'Text' does NOT get copied to the other Sheet as it should unless the string value 'Text' was entered manually or copied by hand into column C.

Please advise on a better solution to have the **.setValue(e.range.getValue())** recognize the auto-fill function values so they get copied to the other sheet(s).

**Example Sheet:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rGns0DGQbjlEpxTbdy1T_-m2oh7eK8tM9xyDzGqahJo/edit?usp=sharing

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Issue:

- `onEdit` doesn't get triggered by data manipulation via script, it is triggered by changes made by user through the Google Sheets UI.

#### Proposed Solution:

- Why not just write the same data to both sheets (`source` and `target`) when running auto fill?
- Leave the trigger as it is for handling manual input (will still copy when manual input is done on source sheet)

#### Code:

```
function emptycellfilling() {
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('source_sheet');
  // target_sheet
  var ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1rGns0DGQbjlEpxTbdy1T_-m2oh7eK8tM9xyDzGqahJo").getSheetByName("target_sheet")
  var empty = ""
  for(var i=2; i<=ss.getLastRow(); i++){
    var val= ss.getRange(i,1).getValue();//select col num

    if(val!=empty){
      ss.getRange(i,3).setValue(['Text']);
      // write to target_sheet what you are writing in source_sheet
      ss2.getRange(i,3).setValue(['Text']);
    }//select target col num and value you want to fill inside, here is 0
  }
}
```

#### Source vs target:

[image: source]
[image: target]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for the time and effort you made!! I really really appreciate it!!

I haven't fully explained my reasoning and for that I apologize.. The same solution I will get here will be implemented in the same project as I also have another onedit I will explain this in another answer as this is too long here .. Thank you though!! Really :D

Comment: Hi @DomePhotography, you're welcome. If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thank you so much your approach is definitely something to consider for this particular problem I will accept it and ask in another forum, no problem! Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

@NaziA

This code takes my input from child sheets and sets the value in the parent sheet:

```
function onEdit(e){
  let ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  let name = ss.getName();
  if (name == "Sheet1" || e.range.rowStart == 1) return;
  e.range.clearContent();
  let db = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  let r = ss.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1).getValue();
  db.getRange(r+1,e.range.columnStart).setValue(e.value);
}
```

Now the parent sheet is linked with another sheet as seen in the code above using openby setvalue, my main issue is that not only is the auto-fill not getting copied into the other sheet.

Rather every code input or values being set by a script into the parent sheet don't get recognized by the **ss1OnEdit(e)** which then writes these inputs to another shared Sheet.

I hope I have clarified my issue better, thank you so much for your effort though!